# Prove that $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}$ with $\mathcal{T}_1$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{B}= \left\lbrace [a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b \right\rbrace$. Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

I have already proved $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ but how to prove that $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}$ ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $\{(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$ is a basis for the standard topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

For every such set we have $$(a,b) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in (a,b)}[\gamma, b) \in \mathcal{T}$$

Furthermore, every open set $U \in \mathcal{T}_1$ can be written as a union of intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ for $i \in I$ so $$U = \bigcup_{i \in I}(a_i, b_i) \in \mathcal{T}$$
since $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under unions. Therefore $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: You really only need to prove that the basis for the standard topology is in $\mathcal T.$ The rest follows by the definition of basis, so everything starting with "Furthermore" is overkill.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know, but maybe OP doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's as simple as noting that

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{p\in(a,b)}[p,b),$$

with a brief argument about why it's enough to show this is true for basis elements, right?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

Let $O$ be open in $\mathcal{T}_1$. Then for each $x \in O$ we have that $(x-r_x,x+r_x) \subseteq O$ where $r_x >0$.

But then $x \in O$ is an interior point of $O$ in $\mathcal{T}$ too, as $[x,x+r_x) \subseteq O$ too, a fortiori. As $x \in O$ is arbitrary, $O$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. So $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}$.